# Codeigniter pagination for multiple parameter search form

Tags: codeigniter, search, parameters, pagination

How to create pagination for multiple parameter search result with codeigniter? For example I need to show data that created by user "Me" and posted on category "News"

Comment: I dont think so, the search form that I want to create is more than one input, like "Advance search"

Comment: please search for codeigniter tutorial on net.tutplus guy explains it well in the video. (or search for query string). http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/

Comment: Use get method for your form & for pagination You'll have to set page_query_string => TRUE